# How I can return IQueryable from calling the service layer and bind it to the UserViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using 3 Tier Architecture in which there is a service layer that have the connection.
I have `UserViewModel` as the presentation model and user as model from EF

Below is my sample code

```
public IQueryable<user> GetUsers()
    {
        entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var query = from u in entities.users
                    select u;
        return query;
    }

private IEnumerable<UserViewModel> GetUsers()
    {
        var database = new entities();
        return database.users.Select(user => new UserViewModel
        {
            UserID = user.UserID,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Password = user.Password,
            Profile = user.Profile,
            Active = user.Active,

        });
    }
```

The code must be like the following:

```
UserViewModel userViewModel= userService.GetUser();
return userViewModel;
```

How can it be possible to return `IQueryable` from calling the service layer and bind it to the `UserViewModel`?

Comment: Its not really clear what your asking. First the methods you have shown return collections, but your trying to assign that to a single object

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to bind it to the UserViewModel

Comment: But your method returns a collection (your can bind a collection of objects to a single object). Do you want to bind it to `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>`, otherwise you would need to supply a parameter so only a single object is returned (e.g. the ID of the object)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I want to bind it to IEnumerable<UserViewModel>

Comment: So what is wrong with `IEnumerable<UserViewModel> model = userService.GetUsers().Select(x => new UserViewModel{ UserID = x.UserID, ..... }); return View(model);` in your controller code?